# Disabling Menu Item

Tags: objective-c, macos

One of my e-books explains how to add a new menu item.  Well, that's not very difficult to figure out.  It's not difficult to figure out how to link an IBAction to a new menu item, either.  But this book and Google search results don't explain how to disable a menu item.  More particularly, I want to disable Preferences and Quit, depending on where window currently appears.  If the application currently shows the Preferences window, I want to disable these menu items.

[image]

Suppose that I have an IBOutlet named **preferencesMenu** and then that I have

```
[preferencesMenu setEnabled:NO];
```

, that won't disable the menu item in question.  So how do you disable a particular menu item?

Thank you for your advice.

Tom

Comment: You do not need to disable the Preferences menu item when the preferences window is already visible. The Quit menu item should never be disabled, period.

Answer (score 8):

NSMenuItems disable themselves automatically only if **both** their target and selector are `nil` and `NULL` respectively.

```
[preferencesMenu setTarget:nil];
[preferencesMenu setAction:NULL];
```

Which a quick test reveals leads to this:

[image]

Comment: How do you re-enable the menu item after it has been disabled as described above?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the target to nil. I'll do the job.

```
[preferencesMenu setTarget:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to do the job.

Comment: And in the interface builder is "Auto enables items" checked ?

Comment: Yes, the checkbox is enabled.

Comment: Thanks.  But there's no change even when I uncheck it.

Comment: Can you reenable the menuItem by just [preferencesMenu setEnabled:YES] after, or do you have to do something else?